# Can't get leanModal to work

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to understand how leanModal works but I can't seem to figure it out. I followed the setup from their site here:http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/?#. However, I don't understand what to do for step 3.

I have set up this function in my html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#btnToCreate-Join').click(function() {
          $("#trigger_id").leanModal();
     });
</script>
```

Step 3 says "call the function on your modal trigger, as follows. Be sure to set the href attribute of your trigger anchor to match the id of your target element."

I am assuming that the modal trigger is the button I want to click to bring up the window. I am not sure what the second sentence means. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

[This is a sample pen demo for you.](http://cdpn.io/wlFjL)
Your html should be like this:

```
<a id="go" name="test" href="#test">Basic</a>

<div id="test">
     bla bla bla
</div>
```

You css should be like this:

```
#lean_overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:100;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
    display: none;
}

#test {
width: 600px;
padding: 30px;
display: none;
background: #FFF;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

Your javascript should be like this:
I assume you have referenced the leanmodal script in your document in head and you are not getting any errors in the browser's console.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#go").leanModal();
</script>
```

Comment: I have changed my code to look like this but I am still not getting the pop-up when I click the button. Am I missing something to include?

Comment: @user2888360 i have given you a sample demo's link in my answer. click  it- check it works and then click on the `Edit this Pen` option at the bottom left of ur browser to view the code.

Comment: @user2888360 ignore the big ugly js code that i have added in the js area in the demo - that is the actual leanmodal plugin code. scroll to the bottom that the trigger statement u need to use - which is under jquery's ready function.

Comment: i copied everything exactly as you have it and nothing pop up. The only think that happens is that it does from url.com to url.com/#test. I can't figure out why it won't pop up.

Comment: @user2888360 u must be getting any errors in the browser's console...??? plz check that first. make sure u r loading jquery first and then leanmodal plugin. add ur html, css, js to ur question

Comment: @user2888360 didnt heard from you. the solution that I gave you works in the demo so plz accept if the demo works for u as well.

Comment: My mistake was forgetting to enclose the function in their example with another dollar sign like this:  $(function(){
   $("#go").leanModal();
  });

Answer (score 1):

Try with $(document).ready() like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnToCreate-Join').click(function() {
            $("#trigger_id").leanModal();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include jquery.leanModal.d.ts in your project from the Definitely Typed library https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery.leanModal

Your Typescript compiler will then have something to reference.

In the CMD line type "typings install jquery.leanmodal --ambient" to install.